# Django : how to delete file record after user close his page?

Tags: python, django

I'm making a simple file resizer with Django, there are 3 fields, `email`, `size`, `image`.

After the user arrives to a the last view where he can download what he resized, I'd like Django to erase the `image` of the `ImageField` to save space on my Django project whenever an user close his window with the final view page.

**I do want to keep the `email` and the `size` as it is**,  so these are the only things that shouldn't be deleted.

I have no idea where to search, I looked into StackOverflows posts and in Django google groups articles but I could not find something to help me, any suggestion on how this can be done ?

Comment: are you sure that you want to handle closing of the window?

Comment: What would happen if the user's browser crashes and doesn't have a chance to notify you the window was closed?

Comment: @sepulchered I don't know yet which is the better way to handle this I thought it was the better rather than setting a date limit to the file.

Comment: @kichik I did not think about it, which is the best way to handle this ?

Comment: @Lindow it depends on what you're building, but a few common options are deleting the image after a few minutes, deleting all old images once a day, deleting it on first view, or deleting it immediately after resize.

Comment: @kichik I'm looking to delete the image after 'x' minutes can you suggest something to do this ?

Comment: @Lindow Celery has nice integration with Django and allows you to both run deferred tasks in X minutes, or a delete task every Y minutes that goes over all the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload - you can try using this method to handle browser close tab with js and send request to django.

But in your place I would prefer timeout after which all images resized certain time ago would be removed (it can be done with simple cron script, possibly with some management command).